# When is it safe to read a file

Tags: c#, file

We have files sent to our FTP (windows server 2008 R2), and one of our services pick the file for processing. The files being to our FTP are of the order 500 MB and more..
How can determine in C# that the file has completed copying into the FTP directory? I dont want to read it while the file is still being copied.

Comment: do you mean 'copied'? or written?

Comment: Try to get an exclusive lock on the file, FileShare.None

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and take an exclusive lock on reading it

```
string filename = "Test.txt";

try
{
   using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
   {
      // Read content here
   }
}
catch(IOException)
{
    // Occurs if the file cannot be exclusively locked.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally the file would be locked by the ftp-server during write operations.

So what you can do is to try open the file with exclusive lock for reading. If that fails (throws an exception) you know the file is not available.